# How to create different table-like layouts with colspan/rowspan based on media queries?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I want to present some content in a table-like layout that changes based on a media query. For large screens, some content is shown in a third table column while for small screens, this content is shown in a extra row. I hope the code snippet makes this clear.

In both cases, I need the width of the cells to be determined by the content of the largest cell. I don't care if the markup is actually a `<table>` or just some `<div>`s.

What I found out so far: Using `display: table` does not seem to be an option since it does not support colspan/rowspan. For a flexbox layout or other `<div>`-based approaches, I just do not see a way to have the width automatically be adjusted to the length of the text and have a common width for all cells of a column.

The only option I see is to add the large cells twice to the markup and hide one of them based on the media query. Is there a more elegant option (i.e. without duplication and without JavaScript)?

```html
<p>layout for large screen sizes:</p>
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td rowspan="2">this is<br>the first<br>multiline cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell B1</td><td>this is cell B2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td rowspan="3">this is<br>the second<br>multiline cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E1</td><td>E2</td></tr>
<table>

<p>layout for small screen sizes:</p>
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell B1</td><td>this is cell B2</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">this is<br>the first<br>multiline cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E1</td><td>E2</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">this is<br>the second<br>multiline cell</td></tr>
<table>
```

**edit:** I noticed that when reducing the problem to an abstract minimum example, I failed to make it clear which assumptions are valid and which are not. I slightly changed the example tables by adding the E1/E2 row. Some additional information:

- The large cells need to span an arbitrary number of rows. (Probably this can be limited to 20 or so in practice.)
- The number of rows in the table is unlimited and depends on the content. The column layout is fixed.

Here is a suggestion for the natural markup using `<div>`s. Think of col1 and col2 to be a list of items while each col3 contains more info about the previous group of items. It would be good to not use the `col3-rowspanN` classes if possible.

```
<div class="table">
<div class="col1">A1</div>
<div class="col2">A2</div>
<div class="col1">cell B1</div>
<div class="col2">this is cell B2</div>
<div class="col3 col3-rowspan2">this is
    <br>the first
    <br>multiline cell
</div>

<div class="col1">C1</div>
<div class="col2">C2</div>
<div class="col1">D1</div>
<div class="col2">D2</div>
<div class="col1">E1</div>
<div class="col2">E2</div>
<div class="col3 col3-rowspan3">this is
    <br>the second
    <br>multiline cell
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! I think your best solution would be to use flex where you can define the flex grow for the sections. Have you thought of using something like bootstrap to make it easier on you?

Comment: I don't have much experience with flexboxes, so can you please explain more about how this would solve my issue? I thought that with flex grow, I have to specify the ratio of the column widths myself. However, I need them to adapt to the content of the cells like a table does. So now, the text "cell B1" defines the width of the first column. If the text changes to just "B1", the width of the cells A1, B1, C1 and D1 needs to decrease accordingly.

Comment: if you want a table like layout changing to a hamburgerlayout, a css grid is the way better solution. even better then using flex-boxes in that case.

Answer (score 1):

First start with a CSS-Grid instead of a table. To make the width of every "cell" use `width: min-content;` and that you have no word-wrap after white space use `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  width: min-content;
}

.doubleRow {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<p>layout for large screen sizes:</p>
<div class="table">
  <div id="A1">A1</div>
  <div id="A2">A2</div>
  <div class="doubleRow" id="firstDouble">this is
    <br>the first
    <br>multiline cell
  </div>
  <div id="B1">cell B1</div>
  <div id="B2">this is cell B2</div>
  
  <div id="C1">C1</div>
  <div id="C2">C2</div>
  <div class="doubleRow" id="secondDouble">this is
    <br>the second
    <br>multiline cell
  </div>
  <div id="D1">D1</div>
  <div id="D1">D2</div>
</div>
```

and for mobile view you can use media query and replace the grid like this:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  width: min-content;
}

.doubleRow {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

#A1, #A2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#B1, #B2 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#firstDouble {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

#C1, #C2 {
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

#D1, #D2 {
  grid-row: 5 / 6;
}

#secondDouble {
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
}
```

```html
<p>layout for large screen sizes:</p>
<div class="table">
  <div id="A1">A1</div>
  <div id="A2">A2</div>
  <div class="doubleRow" id="firstDouble">this is
    <br>the first
    <br>multiline cell
  </div>
  <div id="B1">cell B1</div>
  <div id="B2">this is cell B2</div>
  
  <div id="C1">C1</div>
  <div id="C2">C2</div>
  <div class="doubleRow" id="secondDouble">this is
    <br>the second
    <br>multiline cell
  </div>
  <div id="D1">D1</div>
  <div id="D1">D2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That already helps a lot and shows me how to use grids to have the width defined by the largest element of the column. Unfortunately, I did not make it clear which assumptions are valid for the minimum example. My real data might have way more rows than the example and the rowspan is not always 2. Please take a look at my updated question. Is there a way to achieve the same effect without hardcoding the table layout in CSS?

Comment: well you can auto-align items. however the placement is important in that case. you can span as many "cells" as you want with a grid. For that use `grid-row:`or `grid-column:` and then use ´span x;` while x being the number of cells you want to span for exampel `grid-column: span 15;`if you want to span 15 cells.

Comment: alternativly if you want to use tables which you already familiar with, make 2 tables with different ID's then you can give them the attribute `display: none;`that will not dispaly them. In media queries you can overwrite that by telling them `display: block;`. That way only the correct table will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very helpful example from tacoshy, I somehow made this work and so I am now answering my own question in case it will be useful to someone. I am not very familiar with CSS grids, so please feel free to point out potential improvements.

What I did: First, I changed the markup to have the large cells always follow the groups of small cells. That basically made the small screen layout trivial. In the large screen layout, I used `grid-auto-flow: row dense;` to make the third column move up automatically.

The only thing I find a bit inelegant is that I need to provide the row span explicitly. Using custom CSS properties, I at least found a way that works without defining classes for every possible value.

I am still not happy with the vertical alignment, for which I created [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64417250/1971363).

Code for large screen sizes:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}

.table {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content;
    white-space: nowrap;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    width: min-content;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.col1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
}

.col2 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.col3 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: span var(--span);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="col1">A1</div>
    <div class="col2">A2</div>
    <div class="col1">cell B1</div>
    <div class="col2">this is cell B2</div>
    <div class="col3" style="--span: 2;">this is<br>the first<br>multiline cell</div>

    <div class="col1">C1</div>
    <div class="col2">C2</div>
    <div class="col1">D1</div>
    <div class="col2">D2</div>
    <div class="col1">E1</div>
    <div class="col2">E2</div>
    <div class="col3" style="--span: 3;">this is<br>the second<br>multiline cell</div>
</div>
```

Code for small screen sizes:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}

.table {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
    white-space: nowrap;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    width: min-content;
}

.col3 {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="col1">A1</div>
    <div class="col2">A2</div>
    <div class="col1">cell B1</div>
    <div class="col2">this is cell B2</div>
    <div class="col3" style="--span: 2;">this is<br>the first<br>multiline cell</div>

    <div class="col1">C1</div>
    <div class="col2">C2</div>
    <div class="col1">D1</div>
    <div class="col2">D2</div>
    <div class="col1">E1</div>
    <div class="col2">E2</div>
    <div class="col3" style="--span: 3;">this is<br>the second<br>multiline cell</div>
</div>
```