# How to vertically align grid items in auto rows with row span?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I used a CSS Grid Layout to display data in a table-like manner with the last column spanning multiple rows. While this basically works now , I absolutely cannot get the vertical alignment right. See the following snippet:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  width: min-content;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.col1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  height: min-content;
}

.col2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  height: min-content;
}

.col3 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="col1">A1</div>
  <div class="col2">B1</div>
  <div class="col1">A2</div>
  <div class="col2">B2</div>
  <div class="col3">this<br>is<br>the first<br>very<br>very<br>long<br>cell</div>

  <div class="col1">A3</div>
  <div class="col2">B3</div>
  <div class="col1">A4</div>
  <div class="col2">B4</div>
  <div class="col3">second cell</div>
</div>
```

I want the left two columns to always the minimum height and be aligned with the top of each multi-row cell. In this simplified example, that means that A2 and B2 should move up and be shown right under A1 and B1.

I also tried adding a dummy `<div>` before each col3 and make it take all extra height. But no matter what I tried, the height is always distributed equally among all rows.

Is there a way to make the cells top-aligned with the multi-row cell?

Comment: you want it for this particular case or the layout can be something different? (it's easy for this particular case)

Comment: The three-column layout will be the same, but the real table can have an arbitrary number of rows that will change depending on the content.